# Python execute logic on intervals of time

Tags: python, scheduler, chronometer

I want to **generate** a **value set** based on some of the objects properties, based on a time interval. To generate values I am calling some custom `generateValues()` method.

**Important!** The intervals will have a common divisor (the time intervals are multiples of 5 or of any other number).

Here is my class

```
class RequestTimer:

    def __init__(self, start_date, end_date, interval):
        self.start_date = start_date
        self.end_date = end_date
        self.interval = interval
```

For brevity, I will use 3 objects for an example, but in real-life scenario I may have thousands of Value Sets to be generated

1. Value Set 1 : generated from date x to y on interval of 5 minutes
2. Value Set 2 : generated from date y to z on interval of 20 minutes
3. Value Set 3 : generated from date a to b on interval of 25 minutes

I thought to solve this task by executing the same function recursively every **interval_step** minutes,
and then get all the **iteration * interval_step** divisors, and generate the Value Sets within the available divisors, but in this approach I have to make a lot of checks.

Is there any library which could help me in this?

Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

I have found the solution to this type of tasks by myself: there is a python library called **AppScheduler**, check it [here](https://pypi.org/project/APScheduler/)

Code Example:

```
import os
from datetime import datetime

from apscheduler.schedulers.tornado import TornadoScheduler
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop


def tick():
    print('Tick! The time is: %s' % datetime.now())


def tick2():
    print('Tick2! The time is: %s' % datetime.now())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    scheduler = TornadoScheduler()
    scheduler.add_job(tick, 'interval', seconds=3)
    scheduler.add_job(tick2, 'interval', seconds=6)
    scheduler.start()
    print('Press Ctrl+{0} to exit'.format('Break' if os.name == 'nt' else 'C'))

    # Execution will block here until Ctrl+C (Ctrl+Break on Windows) is pressed.
    try:
        IOLoop.instance().start()
    except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
        pass
```